# How do I generate a new OTR key for Pidgin

Tags: encryption, pidgin

I accidentally leaked my OTR key.

How do I generate a new one in Pidgin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the OTR plug-in of Pidgin forget about one of your own keys, delete the relevant section(s) in `~/.purple/otr.private_key`. Make a backup, if you don't want to corrupt it accidentally.